# Tango is Out of Date - Cannot update Tango Core - Incompatible Device

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm trying to execute the Unity Samples project(Tania Borealis), but it appears that Tango is Out Of Date...  but there are no OTA updates available for me, neither in the Play Store are update available.  But making some search it seems to be a Tango Core app that is replacing the old (Legacy) Tango Core, so I'm trying to update to the new Tango Core app, but the Play Store tells me that "This app is incompatible with your device"... So I don't know what to do.

Just to be sure... What is the latest Tango version?

In my About tablet appear the following numbers:
Kernel Version:
3.10.24-gd25b167
Tango@Atap #1
Fri Jun 24 09:16:20 BST 2016

Build number:
KOT29H.160624

And in the Tango Explorer App:
Tango Service version: 1.37

Answer (score 0):

OK. I have found the problem.   My Tango Core was not up-to-date.  Because the latest version is 1.41.  Everything was caused because I was not able to install the new Tango Core App from Play Store.  It seems this new App is locked outside the US or selected countries.

Answer (score 0):

During July and August all of my multiple Tango Dev Kit (Yellowstone) tablets were failing to update Tango Core in the Play Store. Among other symptoms the Tango Core app screen in the Play Store would say only (otherwise blank screen) "Authentication is required. You need to sign into you Google Account.", even though I was signed in. After some minimally attentive tech support from the Tango team I tried their first suggestion: "Uninstall TangoCore, then reboot the device before using a Tango app (this should take you to the correct TangoCore version)." But though the Tango Core app did update, it didn't make the Play Store problems go away - and I wasn't sure it was fully updated/stable. Even though apps like MeasureIt seemed to start working OK again.

So then I tried their last resort suggestion: factory data reset (FDR): Settings > Backup & reset > Factory data reset > Reset tablet. But it still took a couple weeks of OTA updates before both tablets settled down with the same version as per the Settings > Apps > All > Project Tango Core, a "tania-borealis-release" version.

FWIW the tablets each now have in the Play Store > My apps & games > Installed list both "(Legacy) Tango Core" and "Tango Core" apps. However tapping them in there to bring up their Play Store screen then tapping their embedded App info screenshot to get their status shows a screen without their version info string.

Version management of the Tango Core app is clearly a mess. But it also seems the Tango platform developers are changing how it's managed and (so far) evidently making it a more stable platform.

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did was creating a new Google account located in the US, and then accessing the Play Store from that account, and then I could download the new Tango Core.