# Old sdk versions

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I have an old tablet (Google Project Tango Tablet Development Kit No carrier) which support google tango project (~ 2 years old).
I haven't used it for nearly one year and today I need to work with it again (on Unity3D).

Unfortunately, I read on their download sdk page (https://developers.google.com/tango/downloads) that we need to install Tango Core app on the device. When I try, it tells me that my device is not compatible with my tablet version. I have an old version installed though.

The examples packed with the Unity3D sdk don't work either.
Ar camera scene gives a black screen and motion tracking scene doesn't move at all.

So my question is what is the problem ?

Is the Tango Core installed on my tablet not updated enough to work with the latest sdk ?
In this case I didn't find archive of older sdk on the Tango Project website.

I tried a factory reset just for the sake of it but it didn't changed anything. Can't update tango Core and unity examples don't work.

I am using Unity 5.6.1 and the latest Tango sdk I found (Hopak)

Have you an idea ?

Comment: A firend of mine hasn't enough rep to comment but he wanted to say : Unfortunately it seems the design of Google Play only permits to get the latest version of an app. So, I cannot update the Tango Core app too and I am stuck with the Argentine release. Could you explain how you managed to find the Hopak version?

Answer (score 0):

During July and August all of my multiple Tango Dev Kit (Yellowstone) tablets were failing to update Tango Core in the Play Store. Among other symptoms the Tango Core app screen in the Play Store would say only (otherwise blank screen) "Authentication is required. You need to sign into you Google Account.", even though I was signed in. After some minimally attentive tech support from the Tango team I tried their first suggestion: "Uninstall TangoCore, then reboot the device before using a Tango app (this should take you to the correct TangoCore version)." But though the Tango Core app did update, it didn't make the Play Store problems go away - and I wasn't sure it was fully updated/stable. Even though apps like MeasureIt seemed to start working OK again.

So then I tried their last resort suggestion: factory data reset (FDR): Settings > Backup & reset > Factory data reset > Reset tablet. But it still took a couple weeks of OTA updates before both tablets settled down with the same version as per the Settings > Apps > All > Project Tango Core, a "tania-borealis-release" version.

FWIW the tablets each now have in the Play Store > My apps & games > Installed list both "(Legacy) Tango Core" and "Tango Core" apps. However tapping them in there to bring up their Play Store screen then tapping their embedded App info screenshot to get their status shows a screen without their version info string.

Version management of the Tango Core app is clearly a mess. But it also seems the Tango platform developers are changing how it's managed and (so far) evidently making it a more stable platform.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942599/tango-is-out-of-date-cannot-update-tango-core-incompatible-device) question. The Tango Core app seems to be locked to the US region, so the solution in this case was to create a new Google account and set the location to somewhere in the US. Also make sure you don't have the legacy core app installed instead of the new one (I think the legacy one has 'deprecated' in the title).

As a last resort, you can roll back your SDK version to match the Core version you currently have available (around Argentine most likely).

Not based on anything, but I suspect that the Tango dev team might start moving away from the Yellowstone dev kit and drop support for it to focus on the new commercial Tango devices that are being released.